# How long does my subclass of Android's 'Application' class stick around for?

Tags: android

In my application, I use a subclass of the Application object to store some references to complex objects I need to access from all of my activities.  When my app starts, the startup activity checks one of these references, in this case a Location, and if it is null, it starts the LocationListeners which populate the reference for further use.

If I back out of the app to the launcher screen, and re-launch it, the Application object still has the reference from the previous use a few moments prior.  This is fine, and is what I'd expect, but I'm curious how long the Application object is kept around once I've back'ed out of my application?  (onDestroy() has been called on all activities, nothing in the stack.)

When is it finally killed?  I know it does finally get killed as when I've not used the app in a while, it will search for location on startup (indicating the aforementioned null reference.)

(Also, is storing refs there like that a good idea?)

Thanks in advance gang!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stays around as long as the application is in memory.  It only finally goes away when either someone forcible terminates your application (either using a task killer or from the application settings) or when Android decides it wants to reclaim the memory that your app is using (and this typically only happens when your app has been closed for a while and the phone is running low on memory).

Comment: Oh yeah, now that I've reread your question - it is relatively safe to store references in the Application object, unless your app's components use multiple processes.  If you have Activities in different processes, then they will actually be accessing separate versions of Application.

Comment: Nah, single process here.  Thx again!